# getting error signal 9 every time I try to clone git repository on Mac Pro M1

Tags: git, macos, github, gitlab, apple-m1

I'm trying to clone repository from github (or gitlab) and every time I get this error:

```
% git clone git@github.com:rmccue/test-repository.git
Cloning into 'test-repository'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 9, done.
remote: Total 9 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 9
error: index-pack died of signal 9
fatal: index-pack failed
```

This happens during cloning with SSH. When I use http it just does nothing.

All what I have found in the internet are advices to increase a SWAP memory, but it is not the case as I get this error with all repositories both on github and gitlab.

It is a new machine and git worked fine. The one possible think I have done before, I did installation of Docker and kubectl. But I have deleted all of them including [Oracle VM VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and [Kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/)

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Can you do a shallow clone?

Comment: Are you using an Intel version of Git or an ARM version of Git?  If the former, can you try the latter?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment.
I don't know which one I have, but I re-install it with a brew.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, it looks like I have [found](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/673) an answer.
It is a problem with MacBook M1 Big Sur 11.2

to fix it I run:

```
xcode-select --install
brew uinstall git
(opt)rm -fr /opt/homebrew/etc/gitconfig
brew uninstall gettext pcre2
brew cleanup -s git gettext pcre2 
brew cleanup --prune-prefix
brew install git
```

and it helped.

Hope it will be useful for somebody also.

Comment: Looks like there's a previous git version there installed before the one provided with xcode dev tools. This could rise another problem, to have two installations of git in the same system.